# Pop UINavigationController in AFNetworking failure block

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, afnetworking-2

How do I pop `UINavigationController` in AFNetworking 2 failure block? My code is as follow:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"request": @"get_sth"};
[manager POST:API_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   // success block here, omitted
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // how can I pop UINavigationController here?
    // method 1
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // method 2
    [self.navigationController performperformSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] waitUntilDone:NO];
}];
```

Both method 1 and method 2 are not responding (no error, no warning, no crash, no lag). I thought method 1 is not working because the failure block is running in background thread. So I use method 2. Same response as method 1.

My goal is simple: when the network operation fails, pop back to previous page.

What do I miss out in the case above?

p.s. `self.navigationController` is not null

Comment: have you tried `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // do pop });` -- as a long shot, this should in theory do the same as `performperformSelectorOnMainThread:`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and able to pop viewcontroller without any problem. In `AFHTTPRequestOperation` blocks are invoked on the main queue unless you explicitly set the queue on `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

```c
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *params = @{@“key”: @“value”};
[manager POST:URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   // success code
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  // failure code
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

Also make sure you are not pushing and popping the controller before navigation transition finishes which creates unexpecteed transition state.